# Autocomplete in combobox matching any part of string dictionary with dapper in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, combobox, autocomplete, dapper

I'm trying Autocomplete in combobox matching any part of string dictionary with dapper in VB.NET.

so autocomplete doesn't appear in form4 is there something wrong with my code

Below is the code in Form1 that is perfect that I want to adapt the code to Form4 with same method but I still can't. Please guide me.

Thanks

Code in form1

```
Public Class Form1
    Private CBFullList As Dictionary(Of String, System.Int32)
    Private CBFilteredList As Dictionary(Of String, System.Int32)
    Private ComboBoxBusy As Boolean
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        ComboBoxBusy = False
        CBFullList = New Dictionary(Of String, Int32)()
        CBFilteredList = New Dictionary(Of String, Int32)()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CBFullList.Add("None", 0)
        CBFullList.Add("123 abc", 1)
        CBFullList.Add("12 ab", 2)
        CBFullList.Add("abc 123", 3)
        CBFullList.Add("def", 4)
        CBFullList.Add("ghm 123", 5)
        FilterList(False)

    End Sub
    Private Sub FilterList(ByVal show As Boolean)
        If ComboBoxBusy = False Then
            Dim orgText As String

            ComboBoxBusy = True
            orgText = ComboBox1.Text

            ComboBox1.DroppedDown = False

            CBFilteredList.Clear()

            For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, Int32) In CBFullList
                If item.Key.ToUpper().Contains(orgText.ToUpper()) Then
                    CBFilteredList.Add(item.Key, item.Value)
                End If
            Next item

            If CBFilteredList.Count < 1 Then
                CBFilteredList.Add("None", 0)
            End If

            ComboBox1.BeginUpdate()
            ComboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(CBFilteredList, Nothing)
            ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key"
            ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Value"
            ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
            ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
            ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.None
            ComboBox1.DroppedDown = show
            ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
            ComboBox1.Text = orgText
            ComboBox1.Select(ComboBox1.Text.Length, 0)
            ComboBox1.EndUpdate()
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default

            ComboBoxBusy = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ComboBoxBusy = False Then
            FilterList(False)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub ComboBox1_TextUpdate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.TextUpdate
        FilterList(True)
    End Sub
End Class
```

result in form1

[image: result in form1]

Code in form4 which I want to adapt from the form1 code

```
Public Class Form4
    Private bindingSource1 As BindingSource = Nothing
    Private connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\dapperdemo.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
  Private CBFullList As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Private ComboBoxBusy As Boolean
Private CBFilteredList As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
Private Sub BindcomboboxColorCode()
        Using conn = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
            conn.Open()
            Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Dictionarytest"
            CBFullList = conn.Query(Of Dictionarytest)(sql).ToDictionary(Function(row) row.Result, Function(row) row.Key)
            'conn.Close()
        End Using
        With ComboBox1
                .DisplayMember = "key"
                .ValueMember = "value"
                .DropDownHeight = 80
                .DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
                .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
                .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.None
                .DataSource = CBFullList.ToArray()
            End With

    End Sub
Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBoxBusy = False
        BindcomboboxColorCode()
        FilterList(False)
    End Sub
Private Sub FilterList(ByVal show As Boolean)
        If ComboBoxBusy = False Then
            Dim orgText As String

            ComboBoxBusy = True
            orgText = ComboBox1.Text

            ComboBox1.DroppedDown = False

            Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
                conn.Open()
                Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Dictionarytest"
                CBFilteredList = conn.Query(Of Dictionarytest)(sql).ToDictionary(Function(row) row.Result, Function(row) row.Key)
            End Using
            CBFilteredList.Clear()
                For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In CBFilteredList
                    If item.Key.ToUpper().Contains(orgText.ToUpper()) Then
                        CBFilteredList.Add(item.Key, item.Value)
                    End If
                Next item

            If CBFilteredList.Count < 1 Then
                CBFilteredList.Add("None", 0)
            End If

            ComboBox1.BeginUpdate()
                ComboBox1.DataSource = CBFilteredList.ToArray()
                ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "key"
                ComboBox1.ValueMember = "value"
                ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
                ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
                ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.None
                ComboBox1.DroppedDown = show
                ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
                ComboBox1.Text = orgText
                ComboBox1.Select(ComboBox1.Text.Length, 0)
                ComboBox1.EndUpdate()
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
            ComboBoxBusy = False
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ComboBoxBusy = False Then
            FilterList(False)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_TextUpdate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.TextUpdate
        FilterList(True)
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Dictionarytest
Public Property Key() As Integer
 Public Property Result() As String
End Class
```

result in form4

[image: result in form4]

Comment: Is there a question here? I see code and more code, but there isn't a question mark in the entire post. What isn't working? Are you experiencing an exception? If so, where is that stack trace?

Comment: @ClearlyClueless , `Is there a question here? I see code and more code, but there isn't a question mark in the entire post.` so how can I use the dictionary in form2 with the dapper as in the code in form1?

Comment: This still needs more clarity. Are you trying to use the exact same dictionary from form 1 in form 2? Or are you trying to apply similar behavior? What, specifically, are you trying to accomplish and where are you getting stuck? I don't see a dictionary in form 2 at all currently indicating you haven't tried to consume one in there. Where is the sticking point?

Comment: @ClearlyClueless , `are you trying to apply similar behavior?` yes I tried the same process as per form1. 
I have updated the code in form2 and I get an error  `Value cannot be null` in code `Dim CBFilteredList = conn.Query(Of ColorCode)(sql).ToDictionary(Function(row) row.Colorname, Function(row) row.Colorname)`

Comment: What value is null? Where is that exception message in its entirety? Also, you are creating the `CBFilteredList` inside of a `Using` block which means it will not be accessible outside of that using block. You do have a property with the same name. Perhaps you didn't mean to `dim` a new variable, rather you just mean to write to an existing one?