# why doesn't appear Binding combobox using dictionary with the MS ACCESS database with dapper in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, combobox, binding, datasource

I'm trying binding combobox using dictionary with the MS ACCESS database with dapper in VB.NET.

so I want the binding using dictionary to appear in the combobox which is the `Result` of the table `Dictionarytest`

Is there perhaps something wrong with my code implementation?

Please Guide Me

Thanks

```
Public Class Form4
    Private bindingSource1 As BindingSource = Nothing
    Private connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\dapperdemo.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    Private CBFullList As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
  Private Sub BindcomboboxColorCode()
        Using conn = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
            conn.Open()
            Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Dictionarytest"
            Dim CBFullList = conn.Query(Of Dictionarytest)(sql).ToDictionary(Function(row) row.Result, Function(row) row.Key)
            conn.Close()
        End Using
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Result"
        ComboBox1.DropDownHeight = 80
        ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.None
        ComboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(CBFullList.ToList(), Nothing)
    End Sub
Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CBFullList = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
        BindcomboboxColorCode()
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Dictionarytest
    Public Property Key() As Integer
    Public Property Result() As String
End Class
```

Result db in ms access

[image: db in ms access]

answer update code from @jmcilhinney

```
Public Class Form4
    Private bindingSource1 As BindingSource = Nothing
    Private connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\dapperdemo.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    Private CBFullList As Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
 Private Sub BindcomboboxColorCode()
        Using conn = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
            conn.Open()
            Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Dictionarytest"
            Dim CBFullList = conn.Query(Of Dictionarytest)(sql).ToDictionary(Function(row) row.Key, Function(row) row.Result)
            conn.Close()
        End Using
With ComboBox1
            .DisplayMember = "Value"
            .ValueMember = "Key"
            .DataSource = CBFullList.ToArray()
        End With
    End Sub
 Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 BindcomboboxColorCode()
    End Sub
End Class
```

update code from @dr.null

```
Private Sub BindcomboboxColorCode()
        Using conn = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
            conn.Open()
            Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Dictionarytest"
CBFullList = conn.Query(Of Dictionarytest)(sql).ToDictionary(Function(row) row.Key, Function(row) row.Result)
End Using
        With ComboBox1
            .DisplayMember = "Value"
            .ValueMember = "Key"
                .DropDownHeight = 80
                .DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
                .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
                .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.None
                .DataSource = CBFullList.ToArray()

            End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. What EXACTLY are you expecting the result to be and what EXACTLY happens? One issue is obvious: you have specified the `ValueMember` as "Result" but there's no such member in the items of a `Dictionary`. They are `KeyValuePairs` and have `Key` and `Value` properties; there's no `Result`.

Comment: Also, the way you're calling `ToDictionary`, the `Result` values from your query will be the keys and the `Key` values from your query will be the values. That means that when you set the `DisplayMember` to be "Key", you're actually getting the `Key` values from the `Dictionary`, which are the `Result` values from your query. It's a mess that we can't really unravel because you are expecting us to work out what you're trying to do from code that doesn't do it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , Sorry if I didn't explain enough, I've updated the post. Please Guide Me

Comment: @jmcilhinney , so I want the binding using dictionary to appear in the combobox which is the `Result` of the table `Dictionarytest`

Comment: BTW, there's no reason to explicitly call `Close` on your connection. You are creating it with a `Using` statement and the whole point of that is so it will be implicitly disposed when you're done with it. Disposing an ADO.NET connection object closes it, so you don't need to do it yourself.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , solution I put `End Using` after `End With`

Comment: :) In the `Using .. End Using` block, replace `Dim CBFullList = conn.Query(...` with `CBFullList = conn.Query(...`. Remove the `Dim`. And delete this `conn.Close()`. Seems you're exhausted and need some rest. I'm too because I missed this bug in your previous duplicate question. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77786265/14171304) is clear.

Comment: @dr.null , ;) `replace Dim CBFullList = conn.Query(...` with `CBFullList = conn.Query(...`  This means the same . `And delete this conn.Close()` previously I've commented out But edit by you and you also move the `end using` that the previous one after `end with` So if I debug after edit by you then there is an error `Value cannot be null`

Comment: `Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Dictionarytest"` Do you have such a table in the database? **Dictionarytest** is a **Model** in your code, right? Now, `CBFullList` in `Dim CBFullList = conn.Query(Of ...` creates a new **local** variable, it does not instantiate the **class-level** field. Same name but two different objects. Does that make sense?

Comment: @dr.null , Thank you for your response . `Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Dictionarytest" Do you have such a table in the database?` Yes that's right `Dictionarytest` is a table in the database. `Dictionarytest is a Model in your code, right?` Yes, that's right, it's a model class.  Okay you mean `Dim CBFullList = conn.Query(Of Dictionarytest)(sql).ToDictionary(Function(row) row.Key, Function(row) row.Result)` after this line code `CBFullList = conn.Query(Of Dictionarytest)(sql).ToDictionary(Function(row) row.Key, Function(row) row.Result)` but still error `Value cannot be null.`

Comment: @dr.null , thank you for the response now there is no error but it appears in the combobox as I posted in the screenshot

Comment: Good. Part of my last deleted comment is wrong regarding the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties.  Sorry for that, busy with something here to fix. Now, `DisplayMember = Value : ValueMember = Key`. Just like the answer.

Comment: @dr.null , 
no problem because you have taken the time to provide guidance to me, that is a point that I really appreciate. The problem has been solved with your suggestion. Thank You

Comment: @dr.null , btw I have a post, maybe you can help me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77791876/why-does-binding-combobox-during-form-load-make-it-slow-or-delay-in-vb-net?noredirect=1#comment137151890_77791876)

Comment: @dr.null , actually this post is still related to my other post but has not been solved even though there are no errors . [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77692225/autocomplete-in-combobox-matching-any-part-of-string-dictionary-with-dapper-in-v)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to address here. Firstly, the specific reason that your code isn't working. Secondly, what you should be doing to make it work and work better.

The specific reason it's not working is that you are binding an empty `Dictionary` instead of the one you populate from the query. You declare a field here:

```vb
Private CBFullList As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
```

You then pointlessly create an empty `Dictionary` and assign it to that field here:

```vb
CBFullList = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
```

You then ignore that field and assign your populated `Dictionary` to a local variable that immediately goes out of scope here:

```vb
Dim CBFullList = conn.Query(Of Dictionarytest)(sql).ToDictionary(Function(row) row.Result, Function(row) row.Key)
```

You then bind the empty `Dictionary` that you should not even have created here:

```vb
ComboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(CBFullList.ToList(), Nothing)
```

Even if you fix that by assigning the populated `Dictionary` to the field instead of a local variable, your code is still not going to work, because your binding is wrong.

I would map the `Key` and `Result` properties of your query results to the `Key` and `Value` properties of the `Dictionary` items. That is unless the table may have duplicate values in the `Key` column, but that would be strange, given the name.

```vb
Private CBFullList As Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
```

```vb
CBFullList = conn.Query(Of Dictionarytest)(sql).ToDictionary(Function(row) row.Key, Function(row) row.Result)
```

I would then display the `Value` of the items in the `ComboBox`:

```vb
With ComboBox1
    .DisplayMember = "Value"
    .ValueMember = "Key"
    .DataSource = CBFullList.ToArray()
End With
```

You can use a `BindingSource` if you want but, if it makes sense to use one, you should add it to the form in the designer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have an error `Additional information: Value cannot be null.` in line code `.DataSource = CBFullList.ToArray()`

Comment: @siwa86, if you're getting that error message then you haven't done what I said. Read my answer again and do what I actually said to do. My guess would be that you removed the part where you create the empty `Dictionary` and assign it but you are still assigning the query result to a local variable instead of the field. After you have reread my answer and rechecked your code, if it's still not working then update your question with the new code so we can see what you're actually doing in order to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: I have updated your answer code in the post

Comment: @siwa86, you're wasting my time. I told you what to do in the answer and you're not doing it. I told you again in my comment what I thought you weren't doing properly and I was right, but you haven't bothered to fix it and probably didn't even bother to check your code was correct. If you're going to ask for help then the least you can do is read that help when it's provided and follow the instructions given. I've already given you everything you need to solve your problem. Read my answer AND my comment properly and do what I instructed. I should not need to explain things three times.

Comment: solution I put `End Using` after `End With` . sorry if I waste your time

Comment: @siwa86, Argh! You still didn't follow my instructions. If you're going to do what you said and move the `End Using` then you're still using a local variable, so you should get rid of the field because now it's completely useless. I don't understand how something so simple - demonstrated in code and explained in words - can be so difficult.

Comment: I have updated your answer in the post, please guide me

Comment: The answer I updated has indeed been solved so I want suggestions from you