# why does binding combobox during form load make it slow or delay in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, binding, bindinglist

I'm trying binding combobox with 4 combobox in form load , I use 1 form `Form2` to add and view.

if I comment out the code `BindcomboboxJob2() BindcomboboxJob2() BindcomboboxJob3() BindcomboboxJob4()` in

`Public Sub New()` then it runs normally without delay or slowness

is there something wrong with my code please guide me?

Thanks

Code in form1

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim pservice As New PeopleService()
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadData()
    End Sub
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridView1.Columns("edit") Then
            If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
                Dim transno = DirectCast(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).DataBoundItem, People)
                Using frm = New Form2(transno)
                    If frm.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                    End If
                End Using
            End If

        End If
    End Sub
 Private Sub BtnADD_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnADD.Click
        Using frm = New Form2()
            If frm.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                LoadData()
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Code in form2

```
Public Class Form2
    Private bindingSource As BindingSource = Nothing
    Dim pservice As New PeopleService()
 Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
  BindcomboboxJob1()
      BindcomboboxJob1()
        ComboBox1.Text = "Job1"
        BindcomboboxJob2()
        ComboBox2.Text = "Job2"
        BindcomboboxJob3()
        ComboBox3.Text = "Job3"
        BindcomboboxJob4()
        ComboBox4.Text = "Job4"
    End Sub
 Public Sub New(Transno As People)
        Me.New
        bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of People)(CType(pservice.GetPeopleview(Transno.Transno), IList(Of People)))}
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource
        TextBox1.Text = Transno.Transno
        TextBox2.Text = Transno.Username
        ComboBox1.Text = Transno.Job1
        ComboBox2.Text = Transno.Job2
        ComboBox3.Text = Transno.Job3
        ComboBox4.Text = Transno.Job4
    End Sub
  Private Sub BindcomboboxJob1()
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Job1"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Job1"
        ComboBox1.DropDownHeight = 80
        bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of Job1)(CType(pservice.GetByJob1, IList(Of Job1)))}
        ComboBox1.DataSource = bindingSource
    End Sub
    Private Sub BindcomboboxJob2()
        ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "Job2"
        ComboBox2.ValueMember = "Job2"
        ComboBox2.DropDownHeight = 80
        bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of Job2)(CType(pservice.GetByJob2, IList(Of Job2)))}
        ComboBox2.DataSource = bindingSource
    End Sub
    Private Sub BindcomboboxJob3()
        ComboBox3.DisplayMember = "Job3"
        ComboBox3.ValueMember = "Job3"
        ComboBox3.DropDownHeight = 80
        bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of Job3)(CType(pservice.GetByJob3, IList(Of Job3)))}
        ComboBox3.DataSource = bindingSource
    End Sub
    Private Sub BindcomboboxJob4()
        ComboBox4.DisplayMember = "Job4"
        ComboBox4.ValueMember = "Job4"
        ComboBox4.DropDownHeight = 80
        bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of Job4)(CType(pservice.GetByJob4, IList(Of Job4)))}
        ComboBox4.DataSource = bindingSource
    End Sub
End Class
```

```
Public Class PeopleService
 Public Function GetOledbConnectionString() As String
        Return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\People.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    End Function
    Private ReadOnly _conn As OleDbConnection
    Private _connectionString As String = GetOledbConnectionString()
  Public Function GetByJob1() As IEnumerable(Of Job1)
        Dim sql = $"SELECT Job1 FROM Job1"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of Job1)(sql).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
    Public Function GetByJob2() As IEnumerable(Of Job2)
        Dim sql = $"SELECT Job2 FROM Job2"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of Job2)(sql).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
    Public Function GetByJob3() As IEnumerable(Of Job3)
        Dim sql = $"SELECT Job3 FROM Job3"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of Job3)(sql).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
    Public Function GetByJob4() As IEnumerable(Of Job4)
        Dim sql = $"SELECT Job4 FROM Job4"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of Job4)(sql).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

according to @jimi's recommendation

example

```
Public Async Function GetByJob1() As Task(Of IEnumerable(Of Job1))
        Dim sql = $"SELECT Job1 FROM Job1"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            'Return _conn.a(Of Job1)(sql).ToList()
            Return Await _conn.QueryAsync(Of Job1)(sql)
        End Using
    End Function


Private Async Function BindcomboboxJob1() As Task(Of Task())
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Job1"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Job1"
        ComboBox1.DropDownHeight = 80
        Dim job1Data = Await pservice.GetByJob1()
        bindingSource = New BindingSource(job1Data.ToList(), Nothing)
    End Function

'If the method below is correct, When I call again , I have an error in code `Await BindcomboboxJob1()`

  Public Sub New()
 InitializeComponent()
Await BindcomboboxJob1()
        ComboBox1.Text = "Job1"
    End Sub
```

according to @dr.null recommendation

example

```
    Private bindingSource As BindingSource = Nothing
 Private Sub BindcomboboxJob1()
    If ComboBox1.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then Return
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Job1"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Job1"
 bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = pservice.GetByJob1}
        ComboBox1.DataSource = bindingSource
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
    End Sub
  Public Sub New()
   InitializeComponent()
        ComboBox1.DropDownHeight = 80
ComboBox1.Text = "Job1"
   End Sub
 Public Sub New(Transno As People)
        Me.New
  ComboBox1.Text = Transno.Job1
    End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DropDown

        BindcomboboxJob1()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyDown

        BindcomboboxJob1()
    End Sub
```

Comment: It's up to you to find out where the time is being taken, not us. You can run the code in the debugger and step through it line by line to see which lines take longer to execute. You can also use the `Stopwatch` class to time specific lines or sections of code. Once you know where the time is going, then you can think about what you can do to speed up those parts. If you still need help, you can tell us where the time is going. Also, you haven't us how long anything takes or what your actual expectations are. You need to provide ALL relevant information.

Comment: Most likely, this has nothing to do with `ComboBoxes`. It could well be hitting the database that is taking all the time, especially if you're doing four separate queries. What do your queries look like?

Comment: By the way, it's pointless creating a `BindingList` and binding via a `BindingSource`. Use one or the other but not both. If you already have an `IList`, just bind that to the `BindiingSource`. You really ought to be adding the `BindingSources` in the desiigner too.

Comment: [Start a Task in the Form Shown event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571698/7444103) (second method, probably)

Comment: @jimi , Thank you for your recommendation but that recommendation uses datatable whereas I use dapper with binding source and bindinglist please guide from you

Comment: How does that matter? You use the async methods exposed by whatever tool you're working with. E.g., instead of Dapper 's `[SomeConnection].Execute()`, call await `.ExecuteAsync()`

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `Most likely, this has nothing to do with ComboBoxes. It could well be hitting the database that is taking all the time, especially if you're doing four separate queries. What do your queries look like?` 
I have posted the query you mean or the information you mean

Comment: @Jimi , I've updated the post `according to @jimi's recommendation` is it what you mean? and please guide me

Comment: What data is in these `Job1`, etc, tables? I'd suggest that it's a very bad idea to have a column in a table with the same name as the table and I'm also wondering whether it would be more appropriate to have a single table with an extra column to indicate the number. You could then do a single query to get all the data and that might make things faster. Not sure whether that would be appropriate for the application domain or not.

Comment: `BindcomboboxJob1()` must be `Private Function BindcomboboxJob1() as Task`, where you await `GetByJob1()`. E.g.,  `dim job1Data = await pservice.GetByJob1() bindingSource = New BindingSource(job1Data.ToList(), Nothing)` -- When you call `BindcomboboxJob1()`, you also have to await this method

Comment: @Jimi , 
Thank you for your recommendation, I have updated the post to see if it is correct and there is a warning in the function `Function 'BindcomboboxJob1' doesn't return a value on code all paths. A null refence exception could accur at run time when the rsult is used` please guide me

Comment: `Private Async Function BindcomboboxJob1() As Task` (remember to await it)

Comment: @Jimi , I got an error when I wanted to call `Await BindcomboboxJob1()` . Please Guide me

Comment: @Jimi , 
error like this `Error BC30800 Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses` and  `Error BC37058 'Await' can only be used within an Async method. Consider marking this method with the 'Async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.`

Comment: You cannot await a method in the Constructor of a class; also, `await` can only be used in an `async` method. Since you have a Form, either subscribe to the `Load` event and make the event handler `async`, or override `OnLoad()` and mark this method `async`, then await `BindcomboboxJob1()`; which, as a note, should return the data that `GetByJob1()` generated. You should then set the BindingSource with the data you've got back -- You should probably check the MSDN Docs about the async / await pattern

Comment: I'd suggest not populating the combo boxes on load at all. Fill a combo box when you need to access its items. For example, you can handle the `DropDown` event or `Enter` event (depends on the `DropDownStyle`. The latter is better for the `DropDown` style and the auto complete feature is used) to _null_ check the `DataSource` property. If it's `Nothing`, set a wait cursor, call the bind code of that specific combo box, and lastly reset the cursor. Give it a go.

Comment: @dr.null , thanks your reply, I've updated the recommendation post from you, just so I have to double click in combobox like you see my gif post what might be wrong with my code, please guide from you

Comment: Yes, because 1) You keep setting the `DropDownHeight` property which sets in the base class the `IntegralHeight` property which calls the `RecreateHandle()` method. You need to set this property just once, so move it to the `OnLoad` method or `Load` event. 2) You keep calling the binding code. Call it only if the `DataSource` property `Is Nothing`. Also, what's the business of the `BindingList` here? The `BindingSource` is enough.

Comment: @dr.null , thank you for your response. `1) You keep setting the DropDownHeight property which sets in the base class the IntegralHeight property which calls the RecreateHandle() method. ` for this you mean `ComboBox1.DropDownHeight = 80` 
meaning I moved this code to the load event . `The BindingSource is enough` 
OK, I've changed and updated this post. For point 2 please guide me

Comment: `bindingSource = New BindingSource(pservice.GetByJob1.ToList(), Nothing)`. Add condition in `BindcomboboxJob1` method `If ComboBox1.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then Return`. In the `GetByJob1` method, don't call `.ToList()`. Let the caller cast to the required type if needed. Yes, `ComboBox1.DropDownHeight` is in the right place now. The same applies to the rest.

Comment: Implement the combos `KeyDown` event as well to do the same. `BindcomboboxJob1,2,3..etc`. Remove the `Cursor` lines or move them to the `BindcomboboxJob1,2,...etc.` methods. So, you just call in the `DropDown` and `KeyDown` events the corresponding `BindcomboboxJob#` method.

Comment: @dr.null , Thank you for your reply, I have updated the post, is it correct or is there anything else that needs to be added? Please Guide Me

Comment: Good. Does it work? Post answer if so.

Comment: @dr.null , `Does it work?` works very perfect and goes fast . 
OK this is because of your help and I will post it as an answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to help and recommendations from @dr.null . I thank you very much

```
Private bindingSource As BindingSource = Nothing
    
Private Sub BindcomboboxJob1()
If ComboBox1.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then Return
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Job1"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Job1"
  bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = pservice.GetByJob1}
        ComboBox1.DataSource = bindingSource
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
    End Sub
 Private Sub BindcomboboxJob2()
If ComboBox2.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then Return
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
        ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "Job2"
        ComboBox2.ValueMember = "Job2"
 bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = pservice.GetByJob2}
        ComboBox2.DataSource = bindingSource
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
    End Sub
    Private Sub BindcomboboxJob3()
If ComboBox3.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then Return
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
        ComboBox3.DisplayMember = "Job3"
        ComboBox3.ValueMember = "Job3"
  bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = pservice.GetByJob3}
        ComboBox3.DataSource = bindingSource
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
    End Sub
Private Sub BindcomboboxJob4()
If ComboBox4.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then Return
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
        ComboBox4.DisplayMember = "Job4"
        ComboBox4.ValueMember = "Job4"
  bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = pservice.GetByJob4}
        ComboBox4.DataSource = bindingSource
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
    End Sub
Public Sub New()
InitializeComponent()
        ComboBox1.DropDownHeight = 80
        ComboBox1.Text = "Job1"
        ComboBox2.DropDownHeight = 80
        ComboBox2.Text = "Job2"
        ComboBox3.DropDownHeight = 80
        ComboBox3.Text = "Job3"
        ComboBox4.DropDownHeight = 80
        ComboBox4.Text = "Job4"
    End Sub
Public Sub New(Transno As People)
        Me.New
 ComboBox1.Text = Transno.Job1
        ComboBox2.Text = Transno.Job2
        ComboBox3.Text = Transno.Job3
        ComboBox4.Text = Transno.Job4
    End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DropDown

        BindcomboboxJob1()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyDown

        BindcomboboxJob1()
    End Sub
    Private Sub ComboBox2_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.DropDown

        BindcomboboxJob2()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.KeyDown

        BindcomboboxJob2()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox3_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.DropDown

        BindcomboboxJob3()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox3_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.KeyDown

        BindcomboboxJob3()
    End Sub
    Private Sub ComboBox4_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox4.DropDown

        BindcomboboxJob4()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox4_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox4.KeyDown

        BindcomboboxJob4()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Note, don't use the `bindingSource` field to access the `BindingSource` of any combo box. Instead for example: `Dim bs3 = DirectCast(ComboBox3.DataSource, BindingSource)`. If you need to have class fields, add variable for each. `bindingSource1, bindingSource2 ...`.

Comment: @dr.null , You mean example `bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = pservice.GetByJob1} Dim bs1 = DirectCast(ComboBox1.DataSource, BindingSource) ComboBox1.DataSource = bs1`

Comment: @dr.null , I have problem so I have to click twice in combobox to generate to textbox. Please Guide me. is there something wrong with my code?. I've also updated the answer post

Comment: No, the same does not apply to `PURCHASE`, `PURCHASE` combo box. Delete its `DropDown` and `KeyDown` handlers and handle its `SelectionChangeComitted` event to set `TextBox3.Text = ...`. And don't change the cursor here!

Comment: @dr.null , 
I have used the combobox event `SelectionChangeComitted` , it remains the same, I click twice in combobox

Comment: You need to select an item from the drop-down list to get the event raised not by clicking on the control.

Comment: @dr.null , Yes you are right ,if I do with the keyboard up and down then it appears in the textbox while if I click with the mouse then it must be 2 times, is there a solution so that I can use the mouse once?

Comment: @dr.null , for this You mean example `bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = pservice.GetByJob1} Dim bs1 = DirectCast(ComboBox1.DataSource, BindingSource) ComboBox1.DataSource = bs1`

Comment: No, forget it. That was a side note.

Comment: @dr.null , OK, thank you for your response . btw [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77758780/how-to-reset-bindingsource-bindinglist-sequence-number-in-datagridview-with-vb-n) 
you answered this link post So I made a new post from your answer at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77810257/how-to-reset-bindingsource-bindinglist-sequence-number-update-to-database-with-v) 
please guide from you